# What is meant by “vaccine efficacy?”

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

As a lot of people are aware, vaccines produced by different pharmaceutical companies have different “efficacy rates”:[For example, this chart from the BBC](https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/16D3/production/_116034850_more_vaccines_compared_no_sputnik_v7_3x-nc.png) which shows different rates of how effective vaccines are. My question is, are there different measures of how effective a vaccine are?

e.g.- Are they measured according to how many people, as a percentage, receive immunity? Is it measured according to who retains immunity after trials?

A secondary question is do different pharmaceutical companies have a standard for measuring how effective their vaccines are, or do they each set their own standards? (with or without help from the WHO, etc?)

Comment: I've explained this in this answer: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25442/bnt162b2-mrna-covid-19-vaccine-efficacy-after-1st-dose-explain-the-statistics/25443#25443 and more directly in the linked answer on BIology.SE: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96941/what-does-vaccine-efficacy-mean

Comment: The essence of this question has been asked here repeatedly. Most of the closest matches have been closed as duplicates of [the answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25442/bnt162b2-mrna-covid-19-vaccine-efficacy-after-1st-dose-explain-the-statistics/25443#25443) @BryanKrause linked to above. I believe his answer to that question is definitive, so I'm closing this as a duplicate of that question.